# Rails 4 Associations: undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I've been looking all over the web for an answer to this for the past three hours so I'm going to post a question. I'm trying to create some basic forum software but I am having trouble with my relationships. This is the error I get

```
undefined method `forums' for # <ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Category:0x3706cb0>
```

my categories/index file

```
<% for category in @category %>
            <div class="panel panel-success">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><%= link_to category.name, category_path(category.id) %></h3>
                <h4><%= category.description %> </h4>
              </div>
                <% for forum in @category.forums %>
                  <div class="panel-body">  
                    <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></span><%= link_to forum.name, forum_path(forum.id) %> </h4>
                  </div>
                  <hr />
                <% end %> 
            </div>
            <% end %>
```

Categories Controller

```
    class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

      def index
        @category = Category.all
      end

      def show 
        @category = Category.find(params[:id])
      end

end
```

forums controller

```
class ForumsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
  end
 end
```

category model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :forums, dependent: :destroy
end
```

forum model

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :threads, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and my routes

```
ForumName::Application.routes.draw do 
  root 'static_pages#home'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :categories, :path => "forum"
  resources :forums
  resources :topics
  resources :posts

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',          via: 'get'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',       via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',   via: 'delete'

end
```

Hopefully I've provided enough info if anything else is required I'll update the post. Usually I can work these things out using google but this really has me stumped.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue in action CategoriesController#index

Should be changed to 
@categories = Category.all

because Category.all expects to get several categories, not one

Also you should change categories/index file

```
<% for category in @categories %>
        <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><%= link_to category.name, category_path(category.id) %></h3>
            <h4><%= category.description %> </h4>
          </div>
            <% for forum in category.forums %>
              <div class="panel-body">  
                <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer"></span><%= link_to forum.name, forum_path(forum.id) %> </h4>
              </div>
              <hr />
            <% end %> 
        </div>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was using categories in my controller before not sure why I changed it. So my problem the whole time was writing @category.forums.